# Google maps autoload hidden place in marker location

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Trying to add a marker into a google map from a hidden variable on page load. Is this possible to do based on the address rather than the coordinates?

Code is:

```
  var place = $('#hidden-place').val(); 

    var markers = [];

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
          style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DEFAULT,
          mapTypeIds: [
            google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
          ]
        },
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
          style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
        }
    };

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('google-map'),
                            mapOptions);
```

Comment: If you only have the address, you need to use the [geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) to get the coordinates to display the marker.  possible duplicate of [Google Maps Geocoding a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21411358/google-maps-geocoding-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Geocoding service in the API - take a look at this example https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

In that example it lets you use a free form address and plots the first matching result as a marker.

This would get you started at least.